# Laravel Eloquent Inheritance

Tags: laravel, inheritance, eloquent

I'm new in using Laravel and Eloquent, I used to work with Symfony2 and Doctrine2 in php my php projects, so I have some problems using Eloquent because I think it's different from the ORM Doctrine2, so without wasting more time, here is my problem :

**Migration files :**

**quizzes** table migration file :

```
   public function up()
{
    Schema::create('quizzes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
    });
}
```

**choices** table migration file :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('choices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->text('title')->nullable();
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('quiz_id');
    });
}
```

**quizzes_english :**

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('quizzes_english', function (Blueprint $table) {
    });
}
```

**choices_english :**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('choices_english', function (Blueprint $table) {
    });
}
```

***These 2 files don't contain any columns because I use the inheritance in the model (QuizEnglish extends Quiz and ChoiceEnglish extends Choice), but I'm not sure that this is the right way of thinking !***

The bottom line => when I use the command php artisan migration I get a PDOException, so I think since I'm new in Laravel/Eloquent, the problem might be obvious and I just can't see it :p

**EDIT** :
The message I get when I run the php artisan migrate command :

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access     violation: 1064 You have an error in y se near ') default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in y se near ') default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did not share the message because I think that the mistake should be obvious to someone that have experience with laravel/eloquent, but since this could help you to help me haha, this is the message : [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in y
  se near ') default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL:
  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in y
  se near ') default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci' at line 1

Comment: Edit your question with "PDOException" included and all migrations files.
No one need to see your model for the moment. it has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I can't guess what that would be. but if you're using any foreign keys make them ```$table->integer('whatever')->unsigned();```

Comment: Done. but I get the same problem.

Comment: Can you add ```quizzes_english``` & ```choices_english``` ?

Comment: See the edit...

Comment: Check my answer. If you don't understand what i mean please tell me to explain in it in otherway.

Comment: So if I understand, even if I used the inheritance in the model, I should provide all the columns again in the migration file.

Comment: If yes, than what is the purpose of inheritance in the model ?

Comment: its polymorphic relationship not inheritance .

Comment: Than there no such thing as inheritance in Laravel/Elequent logic (like Symfony2/Doctrine2) ?

Comment: No. See https://laracasts.com/ basic videos (You can see link in laravel main website)

Comment: Ok, Thanks a lot for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **create your models** based on the **migration** (database tables) not the **opposite**.

```
Schema::create('quizzes_english', function (Blueprint $table) {});
Schema::create('choices_english', function (Blueprint $table) {});
```

You need to provide the **columns here**. Or **remove them at all**.